# How to extract keys of certain type from object

Tags: typescript

Lets say I have an interface `Obj`:

```
interface Obj {
  string1: string
  string2: string
  array1: SomeInterface[]
  array2: SomeOtherInterface[]
}
```

How can one extract the **keys** of the interface `Obj` that extends `[]` as a discriminated union type?

Desired output given `Obj` from above:

```
// "array1" | "array2"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html):

```js
type SomeInterface = { tag: 'SomeInterface' }
type SomeOtherInterface = { tag: 'SomeOtherInterface' }

interface Obj {
    string1: string
    string2: string
    array1: SomeInterface[]
    array2: SomeOtherInterface[]
}

type ObtainKeys<Obj, Type> = {
    [Prop in keyof Obj]: Obj[Prop] extends Type ? Prop : never
}[keyof Obj]

type GetArrayKeys = ObtainKeys<Obj, Array<any>> // "array1" | "array2"

type GetStringKeys = ObtainKeys<Obj, string> //  "string1" | "string2"
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgSQHbAgJwGYEMDG0AvFAN5TC4DmAXFAOTxJoY4ET1QC%20AsAFChIsRBADywABZYWWPISglylWgyZjJ09LPadeffgEstbeaIBGAKzL8otqAGdgmI1QCMdR89RUbdzy4AmDycXX1tcTExcEHdhZmM5CABtAF0wqAiokCC49SlMGRNktL49fkFoc0ojAGkIEHsAHnMLABooABVwCAA%20BWs%20OygkgAVMODAoIygAa3q4bCgWlLoW0fGwFKgIAA8MVAATe07uqAB%20KDGJqDpUCAA3LH4uJLmQBaXLEvLTgHEIYAAQUi0TqDX6VVwtXqTRa7WBWUauFQIB6PSAA)

**`ObtainKeys`** is a generic util, which expects two arguments. First one is an Object you want to check, second one is a type you want to extract.

This line: `[Prop in keyof Obj]: Obj[Prop] extends Type ? Prop : never` iterates over all `Obj` keys and checks whether `Obj[Prop]` extends desired type. Please keep in mind, that `Obj[Prop]` is a value and not a key. So, if   `Obj[Prop]` meets the requirements - return `Prop`, otherwise - `never`.

I have used `[keyof Obj]` in order to get all values of our iterated type, because desired `Prop` is in the `value` place and union of any type with `never` - returns you same type without `never`

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Trying to get into the more intermediate areas of Typescript, but this one had me flustered. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I would like to add that this syntax is also possible for the same use case:

```
type ObtainKeys<T, V> = keyof {
  [K in keyof T as T[K] extends V ? K : never]: any
}
```